# opencv detecting blob with a mask

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, feature-detection

I want to detect blobs using opencv `SimpleBlobDetector`, in that class

```
cv::Ptr<cv::SimpleBlobDetector> detector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(parameters);   
detector->detect( inputImage, keypoints);
```

This works fine, until I want to introduce a mask so that the detector only looks for blobs within the mask.

```
detector->detect( inputImage, keypoints, zmat );
```

from the documentation, [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/d13/classcv_1_1Feature2D.html#aa4e9a7082ec61ebc108806704fbd7887), it says:

> Mask specifying where to look for keypoints (optional). It must be a
>   8-bit integer matrix with non-zero values in the region of interest.

My understanding is that the detect algorithm will search only the non zero elements, in the mask matrix. So, I created a mask and populated this way::

```
 cv::Mat zmat = cv::Mat::zeros(inputImage.size(), CV_8UC1);
     cv::Scalar color(255,255,255);
     cv::Rect rect(x,y,w,h);
     cv::rectangle(zmat, rect, color, CV_FILLED);
```

However, it seems that the mask is not doing anything and the detect algorithm is detecting everything. I am using `OpenCV 3.2`. 
I also tried just simple roi, but still the detector is detecting things all over:

```
cv::Mat roi(zmat, cv::Rect(10,10,600,600));
roi = cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);
// match keypoints of connected components with blob detection
detector->detect( inputImage, keypoints, zmat);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the opencv source code to see how the mask parameter is being used?

Comment: @Cristi good idea, I just did not have the time to do that, and I thought someone could have already done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it's not better news. 
Using my installed version of opencv (a 3.1.0 dev version, built September 2016 - I really don't want to reinstall that thing!), I too have this problem. The SimpleBlobDetector just ignores the mask data. There's a quick and dirty work around using a Mat copy with roi (mostly your code, but declare zmat with 3 channels):

```
cv::Mat zmat = cv::Mat::zeros(gImg.size(), CV_8UC3);
cv::Scalar color(255,255,255);
cv::Rect rect(x,y,w,h);
cv::rectangle(zmat, rect, color, CV_FILLED);
inputImage.copyTo(zmat, zmat);
detector->detect(zmat, keypoints);
```

So you end up with your input image in zmat but with the "uninteresting" areas blacked (zeroed) out. Technically, it isn't using any (much) more memory than declaring your mask and it doesn't interfere with your input image either.

The only other thing worth checking is that your rectangle `rect` does specify something that isn't the complete frame - I obviously substituted in my own values for that for testing.